# how to use web socket dependency in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails, websocket

**I got error while inject ngWebsocket dependency in module of myApp.**

Actually i want, if one browser user have make any changes like updation or create new records then it will affect all other browser user who have view this page view..In this i have use angualrjs and grails.

**Console Error:**

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$injector/unpr?p0=%24websocketProvider%20%3C-%20%24websocket

My Code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
var gateApp = angular.module('gateApp', ['ngWebSocket']);
 gateApp.run(function ($websocket) {
    var ws = $websocket.$new('http://localhost:8080/alert/test')
      .$on('$open', function () {
        console.log('Oh my gosh, websocket is really open! Fukken awesome!');

        var data = {
            level: 1,
            text: 'ngWebsocket rocks!',
            array: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
            nested: {
                level: 2,
                deeper: [{
                    hell: 'yeah'
                }, {
                    so: 'good'
                }]
            }
        };

        ws.$emit('ping', 'hi listening websocket server') // send a message to the websocket server
          .$emit('pong', data);
      })
      .$on('pong', function (data) {
        console.log('The websocket server has sent the following data:');
        console.log(data);

        ws.$close();
      })
      .$on('$close', function () {
        console.log('Noooooooooou, I want to have more fun with ngWebsocket, damn it!');
      });
});
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Anyone have idea for this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to pass the dipendency in function this way `gateApp.run('$websocket', function($websocket){//some code})` ?

Comment: is both are same right?

Comment: again it seems like that bro..Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the square brackets, so `gateApp.run(['$websocket', function($websocket){//some code}])`

Comment: ya i have also try that..but no use bro

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $websocket.$new is not a function

Comment: If you are taking ngWebsocket from [here](https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket) you have to change `angular.module('gateApp', ['ngWebSocket']);` to `angular.module('gateApp', ['ngWebsocket']);`

Comment: i have check it..it's correct..and now i have try one code.i got this error..WebSocket connection to 'wss://website.com/data' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301

Comment: gateApp.factory('MyData', function($websocket) {
      // Open a WebSocket connection
      var dataStream = $websocket('wss://website.com/data');

      var collection = [];

      dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
        collection.push(JSON.parse(message.data));
      });

      var methods = {
        collection: collection,
        get: function() {
          dataStream.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'get' }));
        }
      };

      return methods;
    })
    .controller('SomeController', function ($scope, MyData) {
      $scope.MyData = MyData;
    });
});

Comment: if i run this given url, it throw error like that..do you know, how to check web socket connection..

Comment: if i give http://localhost:8080/alert/test in url as well as $websocket('http://localhost:8080/alert/test') instead of wss://website.com/data, it will throw invalid url..error

Comment: either way it cant be http://localhost:8080/alert/test it has to be ws://localhost:8080/alert/test https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket & sure you can check you websocket - not through any form of front end check easily but you can do println "hello open" in your onOpen method of your websocket listener